# National Production/Consumption Data

Tags: international-trade, data-request, international-economics

I've found https://comtrade.un.org/ for country-to-country product import/export data. Is there an equivalent data set for self-consumption, ideally harmonized with the UN's H6 classification system? For example, I can tell from Comtrade that Spain exported \$31B of cars (HS code 8702) in 2020, and imported $13B, but how many of the cars that they produced at home did they buy themselves?